# Complex polynomials... need help

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, complex-numbers

I am very confused on how to start this question, I know that x=0 when i=1/5 and i=1 but not sure where to go from here, any help would be really appreciated.

"Find a polynomial 
P
of a complex variable 
x
that has zeros at exactly the following points:
x=5i−1,x=3i−3.

All these zeros should be of first order. Be sure to expand all products in your answer; also expand products of the form 
(a+bi)⋅x
if they occur."

Comment: You seem to misunderstand what $i$ means. It is not a variable, it is a complex constant such that $i^2=-1$.

Comment: $i=\sqrt{-1}$ since we are talking about complex polynomials, so $i\ne 1/5$. $i$ is not a variable, it's a constant.

Comment: $i$ is the complex unit, not a variable so it's never $\frac15$ nor $1$.

Comment: There's a lot of confusion here. The complex (non-real) number $i$ cannot possibly be the real number $\frac15$ or the real number $1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polynomials can be written in a form that shows its zeros directly, that is, if $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n$ are zeros of a polynomial $p$ and $a$ is the leading coefficient, $p(x) = a(x - x_1)(x - x_2)\ldots(x - x_n)$.
To get the the standard form you only have to multiply it all together.

So in your case, $x_1 = 5i - 1$ and $x_2 = 3i - 3$.
You do not have any conditions on what the leading polynomial coefficient should be, so let it be $1$. That gives you 
$$p(x) = (x - (5i - 1))(x - (3i -3))=  \\\
x^2 - x(3i -3) - (5i - 1)x + (5i - 1)(3i - 3) $$
You are instructed to expand those produsts...
$$ p(x) = x^2 - 3ix + 3x - 5ix + x + 15i^2 - 15i - 3i + 3=   \\\
x^2 - 8ix + 4x -18i -12$$.